# why when checkbox is checked the adjacent checkbox shifts?

Tags: html, css

I'm using background-image:url to import a checkbox and then when that checkbox is clicked the adjacent checkbox shifts to the right, how can I prevent this shiffting movement ? I want the checkboxes to bo fixed in place. The provided links to the images are just an example. Im trying to cause a checkmark to pop up in the box. Here is the snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/0py4enwb/

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Interaktywny poradnik szybkiego startu dla Brackets.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="checkbox" style="background-color:white">
      <form>
      <label class="checkboxlabel" >
        <input class="checkboxparameter" type="checkbox" id="capacity"><span class="inputcheckbox"><span class="inputcheckboxcheckmark"></span></span></input>
      </label>
      <label class="checkboxlabel">
        <input class="checkboxparameter" type="checkbox" id="production"><span class="inputcheckbox"><span class="inputcheckboxcheckmark"></span></span></input>
      </label>
      </form>
    </div>


</body>

<script>
</script>

</html>

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.checkbox{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.inputcheckbox::before{
  background-image:url("/checkbox_notchecked_2.svg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
}




.inputcheckbox::before{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/office/16/000000/add-image.png");
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
}

.checkboxlabel:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox]:checked  + .inputcheckbox > .inputcheckboxcheckmark{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/add-image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
  position:relative;
  left:-75px;
  animation-name:animationcheckbox;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}

.checkboxlabel:nth-child(2) input[type=checkbox]:checked  + .inputcheckbox > .inputcheckboxcheckmark{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/add-image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
  position:relative;
  left:-75px;
  animation-name:animationcheckbox;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}

@keyframes animationcheckbox{
  from{
    transform:scale(0)
  }
  to{
    transform:scale(1)
  }
}

.checkboxparameter{
display:none;
}


.checkboxlabel{
cursor:pointer;
}

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.checkbox{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.inputcheckbox::before{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/office/16/000000/add-image.png");
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
}

.checkboxlabel:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox]:checked  + .inputcheckbox > .inputcheckboxcheckmark{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/add-image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
  z-index: 1;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation-name:animationcheckbox;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}

.checkboxlabel:nth-child(2) input[type=checkbox]:checked  + .inputcheckbox > .inputcheckboxcheckmark{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/add-image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
  position:relative;
  left:-75px;
  animation-name:animationcheckbox;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}

@keyframes animationcheckbox{
  from{
    transform:scale(0)
  }
  to{
    transform:scale(1)
  }
}

.checkboxparameter{
  display:none;
}


.checkboxlabel{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Interaktywny poradnik szybkiego startu dla Brackets.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="checkbox" style="background-color:white">
      <form>
      <label class="checkboxlabel" >
        <input class="checkboxparameter" type="checkbox" id="capacity"><span class="inputcheckbox"><span class="inputcheckboxcheckmark"></span></span>
      </label>
      <label class="checkboxlabel">
        <input class="checkboxparameter" type="checkbox" id="production"><span class="inputcheckbox"><span class="inputcheckboxcheckmark"></span></span>
      </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem was caused by your `.inputcheckboxcheckmark` `span` element. It had `relative` position, which means that even if you visually pulled it left with `left:-75px`, it still kept occupying it's original position on the page creating the empty space between checkboxes.

Comment: You're right. Sometimes it's so obvious. That's why it's good to have someone else look at the code from a different perspective :)

Comment: Yes that's true, when you spend whole day looking at a piece of code, you can not see it with a fresh perspective anymore, hehe ;-)

Comment: Just a quick question. If I would like to create a hover action over the 1st checkbox should this work ?because I cant get it to work `.checkboxlabel:nth-child(1):hover > .checkboxparameter + .inputcheckbox{
  animation-name:animationcheckboxnotchecked;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}

@keyframes animationcheckboxnotchecked{
  from{
    transform:scale(1)
  }
  to{
    transform:scale(1.2)
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Add this code.. because after check your image not in position. now add position absoulte.its working fine

**css**

````
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.checkbox{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.inputcheckbox::before{
  background-image:url("/checkbox_notchecked_2.svg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
}




.inputcheckbox::before{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/office/16/000000/add-image.png");
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
}

.checkboxlabel:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox]:checked  + .inputcheckbox > .inputcheckboxcheckmark{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/add-image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  animation-name:animationcheckbox;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}

.checkboxlabel:nth-child(2) input[type=checkbox]:checked  + .inputcheckbox > .inputcheckboxcheckmark{
  background-image:url("https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/add-image.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  content:"";
   position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  animation-name:animationcheckbox;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
}
.inputcheckbox{
  position:relative;
}
@keyframes animationcheckbox{
  from{
    transform:scale(0)
  }
  to{
    transform:scale(1)
  }
}

.checkboxparameter{
display:none;
}


.checkboxlabel{
cursor:pointer;
}

```
````